# Text and Image side by side with bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to put text and image side by side using bootstrap. I want each to be half of the page and aligned at the top. Can someone help me with this? What I seem to do be doing is not working. Below is my code:

```html
<section class="hero-area bg-white overflow-hidden"> 
  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row justify-content-between align-items-center">
       
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
          <h1 class="text-primary font-tertiary">{{   site.Data.homepage.banner1.title | safeHTML }}</h1> 
          </div> 

        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 mobile-img">
          <img src="{{`images/winningScreen3.png` | absURL}}" class="img-fluid" alt="mobile screen">
        </div>
      
      </div> 
    </div>
 
 </section>
```

Comment: please more clarify your query with screenshot. what you got currently? and what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `col-6` breakpoint to your text and image. so total `col-12` will be divided into `col-6` for your text and `col-6` for your image(ie into two half as you mentioned). Below is the sample snippet

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section class="hero-area bg-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-6 my-auto">
        <h1 class="text-primary font-tertiary">Image text </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 mobile-img">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" class="img-fluid" alt="mobile screen">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```